# Set statement not working inside if clause in sql query

Tags: sql, if-statement, sql-server-2008-r2, set, syntax-error

This is simple query, spend a lot of time but am still not able to get par this.

I have a problem where I need to set a local variable when if condition is true.

```
 Declare @asdf as nvarchar (max)
Declare @nm as nvarchar(30);
select @nm = (Select name from Core.[Lookup] where Id = 1)
Declare @dfdf as nvarchar (max)

if @nm is not null
select @asdf + 'sadf'
endif

select @nm = (Select name from Core.[Lookup] where Id = 15)
if @nm is not null
select @asdf + 'asdff'
endif
```

The above works fine. however if I change the select statement to set statement I get the error. Incorrect syntax near 'endif'.

```
Declare @asdf as nvarchar (max)
Declare @nm as nvarchar(30);
select @nm = (Select name from Core.[Lookup] where Id = 1)
Declare @dfdf as nvarchar (max)

if @nm is not null
set @asdf = 'sadf'
endif

select @nm = (Select name from Core.[Lookup] where Id = 15)
if @nm is not null
set @asdf = 'asdff'
endif
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no `endif` keyword in `T-SQL`, proper query would look like:

```
Declare @asdf as nvarchar (max)
Declare @nm as nvarchar(30);
select @nm = (Select name from Core.[Lookup] where Id = 1)
Declare @dfdf as nvarchar (max)

if @nm is not null
begin
     set @asdf = 'sadf'
end

select @nm = (Select name from Core.[Lookup] where Id = 15)
if @nm is not null
begin
   set @asdf = 'asdff'
end
```